# Can you give links numerical values and add several together

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to give several links numerical values which can be added together after an ondrop event. 
I have made 4 of these dropdown menu buttons:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Group  1 </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" draggable="true" id="drag1" ondragstart="drag(event)"> Link 1 </a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" draggable="true" id="drag2" ondragstart="drag(event)"> Link 2 </a> 
    <a href="#" target="_blank" draggable="true" id="drag3" ondragstart="drag(event)"> Link 3 </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also made 8 of these divs, where the links are supposed to be dropped:

```
<div class="element-box element1" ondrop="drop(event)" id="box1" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
```

I managed to make the links droppable into the boxes using this js code:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
 document.getElementById("dvalue").innerHTML = "test"; 
}
```

But the problem is, I cant wrap my head around to figure how to add numerical values to the different links, which are supposed to be added together after one link is dropped into each of the 8 boxes I have made.
I have tried to find a solution to my problem for several days, but I haven't been able to find anything that can help me. Can anyone help me, because I have no idea where to start?

Comment: You might be interested in using a "data-" attribute, like <a data-numerical-value="#">. Then element.getAttribute

Comment: I was just about to say... I use `data-` attributes all over the place. So `<a data-num="5"...>` and `var num = el.getAttribute('data-num')`